# Sound Output Device disappears after turn off display by energy saving

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11, troubleshooting, energy-saving

Related to this question on W7 in 2011 without any answer:
[Device disconnected sound in Windows 7 while monitor is in energy save](https://superuser.com/questions/340828/device-disconnected-sound-in-windows-7-while-monitor-is-in-energy-save?rq=1)

I don't know if it's the same issue.

I've a TV as monitor with HDMI connection and Windows 11.
After energy plan options turns off the display after n minutes, when recover the display from his sleep, the sound device doesn't appear, and the default output device is another one.
I can only recover the device after "troubleshooting output devices" in sound configuration, but is really annoying.

How can I resolve this and avoid this without disabling display turn off in energy options?

I'm working with a Gigabyte Nvidia 1060 6GB

Comment: Manually turn the TV on and off? Which TV are we talking about?

Comment: @Gantendo found it in english, I will update my question